# Is this possible with the CASE expression in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, case

Everything I've read about using CASE implies that it's only possible to change the contents of the individual field within the column it references. Is there a way to reference a field within another table?

Instead of (just to use a random example from the internet)

```
SELECT daysName,
       CASE daysName 
         WHEN "Sunday" THEN "Holiday"
```

I want something like:

```
CASE table1.column1   
  WHEN table3.column1 = "Yes" THEN table1.column1 + 80
```

If not, how do I do this?

These tables have primary and foreign keys so I am able to use joins.

Comment: What would this hypothetical statement of yours do?

Comment: Did you try this in MySql and it not work?  If so, what problems are you having?

Comment: If the value in table3.column1 is Yes in whatever row it corresponds to, table1.column1 would be its current value + 80. If not, it would just be its current value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you could turn the `case` expression into

```
CASE table3.column1
  WHEN 'Yes' THEN (table1.column1 + 80)
  ELSE table1.column1
END
```

Or, you could use `IF`:

```
table1.column1 + IF(table3.column1 = 'Yes', 80, 0)
```

You'll need to join `table3` either way, of course, and you might want to give that value an alias, since it's no longer strictly a field in the DB.  (MySQL will return that whole expression as the column name.)

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
CASE table1.column1   
  WHEN table3.column1 = "Yes" THEN table1.column1 + 80
```

...should return a syntax error for attempting to use both syntax options for a CASE expression.  Without more information, it should be:

```
CASE 
  WHEN table3.column1 = "Yes" THEN table1.column1 + 80
```

..because there's nothing in the example to say you're using the table1.column1 for evaluation.

Next - to use the `table3.column` comparison, you need a join.  That can be an INNER or OUTER JOIN, possibly a cartesian product (CROSS JOIN)... but you haven't provided information about what the relationship between the tables is.